# How do I use .find for the last five days in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find, date

Have a model called contact_email.date_sent

I want to be able to run a report which displays all those where the date_sent range is between date.today and date.today 5 days ago.

I assume I use something like

```
@send_emails = Contact_Email.find(:conditions=> ???)
```

But not clear what exactly is the best way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ContactEmail.all(:conditions => ["date_sent >= ?", 5.days.ago.to_date])
```

This approach is faster than using `BETWEEN` clause( assuming `date_sent` is indexed)

**Caveat:**

Value of `date_sent` column should be less than current date.

**Edit 1**

To add an index in migration:

```
add_index :contact_emails, :date_sent
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it so that I can get what has been sent Monday through Friday of the week that Date.today is?

Comment: HOw do I create a migration to add date_sent as an index (date_sent alrady exists, but wasn't set as index)?

Comment: Updated the answer, take a look.

Comment: Hi, there, I have another question, I was wondering if you could help me...are you familiar with Single Table INheritances?

Answer (score 1):

`ContactEmail.find(:conditions => ['date_sent BETWEEN ? AND ?', Date.today, 5.day.ago.to_date])`

Comment: You could also just use >, since presumably your database does not contain emails from the future.

Comment: Correct, but this condition helps finding stuff in retrospective.

Answer (score 0):

If it's something you will use regularly, why not put a named_scope in the model:

```
named_scope :recent, lambda { |*args| {:conditions => ["date_sent > ?", (args.first || 5.days.ago)]} }
```

which will let you write:

```
ContactEmail.recent
```

for the last 5 days worth, or use the arg to specify your own time frame e.g. the last two weeks:

```
ContactEmail.recent(2.weeks.ago)
```